# Is there a grammar of Middle Tamil?

Tags: reference-request, tamil

I am studying the *Thiruppavai*, a Middle Tamil poem, as a linguist and I wondered if any of you by any chance know of resources pertaining the grammar of Middle Tamil. Overviews of the history of Tamil are also acceppted.

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Middle Tamil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_Tamil) has some references (now that I have copied them from the Tamil Language article!). Of those Meenakshisundaran, T.P. (1965), A History of Tamil Language, Poona: Deccan College looks the most promising from its title, but I haven't seen it and I know nothing of Middle Tamil.